# pytorchでの学習したモデルの呼び出しとクラスの呼び出しの方法

Tags: python, pytorch

pytorchでの機械学習用のコードを実装し，次に予測するコードを実装しています．
pytorchで学習したモデルを呼び出そうとしたら，モデルの呼び出しではなく，なぜか，呼び出したプログラムが開始してしまします．どなたか，正しい学習済みのモデルとクラス及び変数の呼び出し方を教えてください．2つのプログラムファイルは同じディレクトリにあり，学習プログラムはRECurrentSNN.py，予測プログラムはpredicted.pyです．

モデルのコードとクラス

```
    import torch
    import torch.nn as nn
    import numpy as np
    from bindsnet.network import Network
    from bindsnet.network.nodes import Input, LIFNodes
    from bindsnet.network.topology import Connection
    from bindsnet.network.monitors import Monitor
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    from bindsnet.encoding.loaders import poisson_loader
    # モデルの定義
    class LogisticRegression(nn.Module):
        def __init__(self, input_size, num_classes):
            super(LogisticRegression, self).__init__()
            self.linear = nn.Linear(input_size, num_classes)
        def forward(self, x):
            output = self.linear(x)
           _, predicted = torch.max(output,1) #定義しなおしました
            return output

     network = Network(dt=1.0)
     input_size = 64
     num_classes = 6
     time = 32      
     _BATCH_SIZE = 300
     num_epochs = 100

     inpt = Input(64, shape=(1,64))
     output = LIFNodes(64, thresh=-52 + torch.randn(64))  # m1のb
     network.add_layer(inpt, name='A')
     network.add_layer(output, name='E')
     network.add_connection(Connection(inpt, output, w=torch.randn(inpt.n, output.n)), 'A', 'E')
     network.add_connection(Connection(output, output, w=0.5*torch.randn(output.n, output.n)), 'E', 'E')

     spikes = {}
     for l in network.layers:
         spikes[l] = Monitor(network.layers[l], state_vars=["s"], time=time)
         network.add_monitor(spikes[l], name="%s_spikes" % l)
         voltages = {"E": Monitor(network.layers["E"], ["v"], time=time)}
         network.add_monitor(voltages["E"], name="E_voltages")

    npzfile = np.load("C:/Users/nama/Desktop/myo-python-1.0.4/myo-armband-nn-master/data/train_set.npz")
    x = npzfile['x']
    y = npzfile['y']
    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
    # tensor型に変換
    x_train = torch.from_numpy(x_train).float()
    y_train = torch.from_numpy(y_train).float()
    x_train = torch.clamp(x_train, min=0, max=1000)
    x_test = torch.from_numpy(x_test).float()
    y_test = torch.from_numpy(y_test).long()
    x_test = torch.clamp(x_test, min=0, max=1000)
    loader = zip(poisson_loader(x_train * 0.64, time=64), iter(y_train))
    training_pairs = []
    for i, (datum, y_train) in enumerate(loader):
        network.run(inputs={"A": datum}, time=time, input_time_dim=1)
        training_pairs.append([spikes['E'].get('s').sum(0), y_train])
        network.reset_state_variables()
        if (i + 1) % 10 == 0: print('Train progress: (%d / 40)' % (i + 1))
        if (i + 1) == 40: print(); break

    model = LogisticRegression(input_size, num_classes); criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()   # m2に相当
    optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.005)
    # スパイクとラベルのトレーニング
    correct, total = 0, 0
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
           for i, (s, y_train) in enumerate(training_pairs):
               optimizer.zero_grad()
               output = model(s.float())
               y_train = torch.reshape(y_train, (-1,))  # y_trainのサイズを[1], output=[1.6]
               y_train = y_train.view(-1, 6)
               y_train = torch.argmax(y_train, dim=-1)
               loss = criterion(output,  y_train.long())
               loss.backward(); optimizer.step()
               _, predicted = torch.max(output, 1)
                total += 1
               correct += int(predicted == y_train.long())
       print('Accuracy of logistic regression on train examples: %2f %%\n ' % (100 * correct / total))


     loader = zip(poisson_loader(x_test * 0.64, time=64), iter(y_test))
     test_pairs = []
     model.eval()
     for i, (datum, y_test) in enumerate(loader):
         network.run(inputs={"A": datum}, time=time, input_time_dim=1)
         test_pairs.append([spikes['E'].get('s').sum(0), y_test])
         network.reset_state_variables()
         if (i + 1) % 100 == 0: print('Test progress: (%d / 500)' % (i + 1))
         if (i + 1) == 500: print(); break

     correct, total = 0, 0
     for s, y_test in test_pairs:
         output = model(s.float()); _, predicted = torch.max(output, 1)
         y_test = torch.argmax(y_test)
         total += 1
         correct += int(predicted == y_test)
 
    print('Accuracy of logistic regression on test examples: %2f %%\n ' % (100 * correct / total))
    torch.save({
            'epoch': epoch,
            'model_state_dict': model.state_dict(),
            'optimizer_state_dict': optimizer.state_dict(),
            'loss': loss,
            }, "C:/Users/name/Desktop/myo-python-1.0.4/bindsnet-master/bindsnet/pytorchsession/snn.pth")

    checkpoint = torch.load("C:/Users/name/Desktop/myo-python-1.0.4/bindsnet- 
    master/bindsnet/pytorchsession/snn.pth")
    model.load_state_dict(checkpoint["model_state_dict"])
    optimizer.load_state_dict(checkpoint["optimizer_state_dict"])
    epoch = checkpoint["epoch"]

    optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.1)
    torch.save(optimizer.state_dict(), "C:/Users/name/Desktop/myo-python-1.0.4/bindsnet- 
    master/bindsnet/pytorchsession/optimizer.pth" )
    optimizer2 = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.1)
    optimizer2.load_state_dict(torch.load("C:/Users/name/Desktop/myo-python-1.0.4/bindsnet- 
    master/bindsnet/pytorchsession/optimizer.pth"))
```

```
"""
予測プログラム
"""
    from collections import deque
    from threading import Lock
    import myo
    import time
    import numpy as np
    from time import sleep
    import torch
    import torch.nn as nn
    from bindsnet.RECurrentSNN import LogistiRegression
    model_path = "C:/Users/name/Desktop/myo-python-1.0.4/bindsnet- 
    master/bindsnet/pytorchsession/snn.pth"

    class MyListener(myo.DeviceListener):
        def __init__(self, queue_size=8):
          self.lock = Lock()
        self.emg_data_queue = deque(maxlen=queue_size)
        self.orientation_data_queue = deque(maxlen=queue_size)
        self.acceleration_data_queue = deque(maxlen=queue_size)
        self.gyroscope_data_queue = deque(maxlen=queue_size)
        self.rssi_data_queue = deque(maxlen=100)
        self.pose = myo.Pose.rest
        self.connected = False
        self.battery_level = 100
        self.emg_enabled = False
        self.locked = False
        self.rssi = None
        self.emg = None
        self.device_name = None
        self.device = None
        self.myo_firmware = None
        self.arm = None
        self.x_direction = None
        self.sync = None

      def get_emg_data(self):
        with self.lock:
            return list(self.emg_data_queue)

    def get_orientation_data(self):
        with self.lock:
            return list(self.orientation_data_queue)

    def get_gyroscope_data(self):
        with self.lock:
            return list(self.gyroscope_data_queue)

    def get_accelerometor_data(self):
        with self.lock:
            return list(self.acceleration_data_queue)

      if __name__ == '__main__':

        myo.init(bin_path=r'C:\Users\name\Desktop\myo-sdk-win-0.9.0\bin')
        HUB = myo.Hub()
        listener = MyListener()
        start = time.time()
        temp = []
        with HUB.run_in_background(listener.on_event):
            while True:
            data = listener.get_emg_data()
            if time.time() - start >= 1:
                response = np.argmax(np.bincount(temp))
                print("Predicted gesture: {0}".format(response))
                temp = []
                start = time.time()
            if len(data) > 0:
                tmp = []
                for v in listener.get_emg_data():
                    tmp.append(v[1])
                tmp = list(np.stack(tmp).flatten())
                if len(tmp) >= 64:
                    pred = torch.mean(predicted, feed_dict={x: np.array([tmp])})
                    #pred = sess.run(y_pred_cls, feed_dict={x: np.array([tmp])})
                    temp.append(pred[0])
            sleep(0.01)
```

Answer (score 0):

おかしな点としては、以下で

```
pred = torch.mean(predicted, feed_dict={x: np.array([tmp])})
```

`predicted`を引数で渡しているけど、`predicted`は貰ったソースコード上定義されて無さそう

Comment: predictedを定義しなおしましたが，同じエラーがでます．どのようにすればいいでしょうか？

Comment: 修正後のソースコードが見たいのとインデントが間違えてそうなのでgistやGitHubにコードを公開できませんか？